# Added custom entry details fields

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I'm looking to add a custom fields to the `details` section on the right of the entry edit view in the control panel.

I know that in Craft 2 this was possible using:
`Craft::$app->view->hook('cp.entries.edit.details', functionThatReturnsView())`

Is there a more Craft 3 way to do this or do we still use the Craft 2 API for this kind of extension to control panel?

Comment: Have you tried $view->hook('cp.entries.edit.details', functionThatReturnsView())

Comment: Yep, and it works. But it seems strange that it would be done that way, would have expected it to follow the Craft 3 way of doing things.

Comment: Want to add that as an official answer, @IndigoViking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$view->hook('cp.entries.edit.details', functionThatReturnsView())
```

Is the correct way in Craft 3.